# "All the thermodynamic properties of our system"?

Tags: thermodynamics

Trying to grasp this quote from Schroeder's textbook
[image]

Why are the entropy, pressure, and chemical potential "all the thermal properties?" What about $T$, $U$, $V$? This may have something to do with so-called "natural variables." Not sure.

Thoughts?

Comment: First thing, please make the relevant parts of the image text, so that the question is searchable. Second the author is speaking about the general procedure followed to obtain them, he is not claiming those are all. Schröder says "In this way".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that Schroeder is talking about the canonical partition function. The partition function related to the canonical ensemble. The canonical ensemble is characterized by the the knowledge of those quantities, as Le-Bellac in "Equilibrium and Non-Equilibrium Thermodynamics" puts it:

"The canonical ensemble corresponds to exact knowledge of the volume, V, the
number of molecules, N, as well as the average value of the Hamiltonian E (a statistical quantity)."

Also temperature $T$ defines the very value of $\beta=\dfrac{1}{kT}$ that you need in order to calculate the partition function. So all these quantities you need to know previously in order to calculate $P$, $\mu$, $S$ etc

In each ensemble you have quantities that are required to be fixed and quantities that can be calculated when those quantities are fixed.

Comment: AHHHH of course! Thank you! I find Huang is better at making sure the reader knows what ensemble they're currently learning about, with his phase space formalism and whatnot. Cheers!